# Automatically page Kendo grid to the selected row on load

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Kendo grids server-side operations (paging, sorting, filtering). Some of these grids may have 10+ pages of data.

Users may select a row on page 3 and save the selection. Later the user will reload that same grid. The grid loads to show page 1. What I would like is for the grid to automatically load to the page with the selected row. In my example, the grid would load with page 3 selected because the selected row is on page 3.

I am not able to find a server-side solution to this that doesn't require overly complex coding. I assume there is an easier way to do this which I am missing. Can someone tell me if there is an easier way to auto-page to the selected row when doing server-side operations with Kendo UI v. 2017.2.504(R3 2017) and .NET Framework v 4.7.?

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/persist-row-selection-while-paging

Comment: Yes, that will persist the selected row. However, it does not load the grid to the page with the persisted row.

The persisted row may be on page 10 of 20. I want the grid to load automatically on page 10 wit the selected row.

Comment: @Wylice I am facing the same issue, were you able to find the answer?
Thanks.